# Reading from IEnumerable and adding items dynamically to List using foreach in c#

Tags: c#, list, initialization, ienumerable

I'm using a stored proc(Dapper) to fetch data in an IEnumerable. To screen some unwanted characters and remove leading/trailing spaces, I have created a foreach loop, and then add the data to a List.

The following code is working and giving desired results, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way or if there's a better way of doing it. Particularly, I'm sure if I'm initializing class appropriately and then adding to list.

```
public class LoadBOUserLogin
    {
        public string LOGIN_ID { get; set; }

        public string EMP_ID { get; set; }

        public string CODE { get; set; }
        public LoadBOUserLogin() { }
        public LoadBOUserLogin(string LOGIN_ID, string EMP_ID, string CODE)
        {
            this.CODE = CODE;
            this.LOGIN_ID = LOGIN_ID;
            this.EMP_ID = EMP_ID;
        }

    }  

private static IEnumerable<BOUserLogin> LoadBOUserLogin()
        {
            IEnumerable<DTO.BOUserLogin> items = new List<DTO.BOUserLogin>(0);

            var userLoginList = new List<BOUserLogin>();
            var userLogin = new BOUserLogin(); //initializing class
            try
            {

                string strQuery = @"[dbo].[BOUSER_SEL_Login]";


                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connections.GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    
                    items = con.Query<DTO.BOUserLogin>(strQuery, commandTimeout: 120, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }

        //removing unwanted charaters and trim
                foreach (var x in items)
                {
                   
                    userLogin.LOGIN_ID = Regex.Replace(x.LOGIN_ID ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();
                    userLogin.CODE = Regex.Replace(x.CODE ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();
                    userLogin.EMP_ID = Regex.Replace(x.EMP_ID ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();

                    userLoginList.Add(new BOUserLogin(userLogin.LOGIN_ID, userLogin.CODE, userLogin.EMP_ID));
                    
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
        throw ex;
            }
            
            return userLoginList;
        }
```

Comment: why not to move clean up and trim in to stored proc?

Comment: I'm doing it already using LTrim and RTrim in the stored proc, but still did not get desired results. So I wasn't sure what kind of spaces are those. After doing Regex and Trim() in c#, it is working fine

Comment: `catch (Exception ex){throw ex;}` what on earth is that for? It's just going to wipe the stack trace. At the very least do `throw;` not `throw ex;` or better just remove the whole `catch`

Comment: @Charlieface probably cargo cult (or just copy-paste). The only real use case I know is to avoid exception filters running in a wrong context - but code shown does not do any elevation - so I see no reason to have it.

Comment: @SilverFish you probably wanted to post that on [CodeReview.se]... or specifically ask for particular improvement. (Obviously for SO you need to remove randomly added code like that semi-empty exception block).

Comment: @SilverFish, try use unicode char representation to replace. such as replace(column, Char(126), '') - would replace unicode char \u007E which related to tilda: ~

Comment: for try/catch I do have code. did not post here since not relevant to what I'm asking

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, wasn't aware of Code Review. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close! First, I think your class should be named `BOUserLogin`, right?

```
public class BOUserLogin
{
    public string LOGIN_ID { get; }
    public string EMP_ID { get; }
    public string CODE { get; }

    public BOUserLogin() { }

    public BOUserLogin(string LOGIN_ID, string EMP_ID, string CODE)
    {
        this.CODE = CODE;
        this.LOGIN_ID = LOGIN_ID;
        this.EMP_ID = EMP_ID;
    }
}
```

Then your `LoadBOUserLogin` method needs a couple of minor changes, which I have commented in the code below:

```
private static IEnumerable<BOUserLogin> LoadBOUserLogin()
{
    IEnumerable<DTO.BOUserLogin> items = new List<DTO.BOUserLogin>(0);

    var userLoginList = new List<BOUserLogin>();

    // This is not required
    // var userLogin = new BOUserLogin(); //initializing class

    try
    {
        string strQuery = @"[dbo].[BOUSER_SEL_Login]";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connections.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            items = con.Query<DTO.BOUserLogin>(strQuery, commandTimeout: 120, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }

        // Removing unwanted characters and trim
        foreach (var x in items)
        {
            // Assign the results to variables...
            var loginId = Regex.Replace(x.LOGIN_ID ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();
            var code = Regex.Replace(x.CODE ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();
            var empId = Regex.Replace(x.EMP_ID ?? string.Empty, @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty).Trim();

            // ...and use the variables to instantiate the BOUserLogin class.
            userLoginList.Add(new BOUserLogin(loginId, code, empId));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return userLoginList;
}
```

Finally, the catch has a couple of issues, which I will leave for you to investigate :)

Hint 1: Search for 'rethrow to preserve stack trace'.

Hint 2: Is the catch actually doing anything?

Comment: sorry about that. yes, try/catch has exception handling code